# How to express date literal in SpEL?

Tags: spring, literals, spring-el

In the official [spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-ref-literal), it says

> The types of literal expressions supported are strings, dates, numeric values (int, real, and hex), boolean and null.

But there aren't examples of date literal in this document. I searched on the Internet but nothing was found.

**So how to express date literal in SpEL?**

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is an spring reference document issue. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14987.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that date literals [didn't make the cut](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/efee3b34346202b5397ecceea5a9e023001101b4). I have opened a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14987) against the reference document.

It's easy enough to [register your own function](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions) (e.g. one that uses a `SimpleDateFormatter` to parse the date).

Comment: So glad to find an issue in the reference document:) I will use the [method invoking expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-methods) and accept this answer.